# Why would the similarity matrix of a gensim Word2VecKeyedVectors be very sparse compared to to the model itself?

Tags: python, gensim

In general, I have the following code:

```py
import gensim
import gensim.downloader as api

model = api.load('word2vec-google-news-300')
...
matrix = model.similarity_matrix(dictionary, tfidf=None, threshold=0.0,
    exponent=2.0, nonzero_limit=100)
...
```

I am using the following dictionary for the variable dictioanry:

```
4
0   apple   2
1   eaten   1
10  google  1
2   half    1
3   iphone  2
4   is  2
7   lost    2
11  missing 1
5   model   1
8   my  2
9   phone   2
12  pixel   1
6   plus    1
13  somewhere   1
```

So when I compute the similarity between 'phone' and 'iphone', I get a nonzero value.

```py
sim_match.model.similarity('phone','iphone')
>> 0.33964303
```

But at the index 3,9 of matrix (the similarity of 'phone' and 'iphone' in the similarity matrix), I get a zero entry.

```py
matrix[3,9]
>> 0.0
```

As a matter of fact, almost all entries are zero.

```py
print(matrix)
>>  (0, 0)        1.0
>>  (1, 1)        1.0
>>  (2, 2)        1.0
>>  (3, 3)        1.0
>>  (4, 4)        1.0
>>  (5, 5)        1.0
>>  (6, 6)        1.0
>>  (7, 7)        1.0
>>  (11, 7)       0.21569395
>>  (8, 8)        1.0
>>  (9, 9)        1.0
>>  (10, 10)      1.0
>>  (11, 11)      1.0
>>  (7, 11)       0.21569395
>>  (12, 12)      1.0
>>  (13, 13)      1.0
```

Only the words 'lost' and 'missing' have a nonzero similarity and aren't equivalent.

I do know that the matrix is a numpy sparse matrix. Maybe its the parameters I'm passing, but I am confused as to why most of the elements in the matrix are zero. The parameters I passed, based on the documentation, seem that they shouldn't be causing so many entries to be 0. I do note that the nonzero_limit is 100, but shouldn't there be a hundred nonzero entries?

Is there anyway I could fix or get around this?

Comment: I'm not sure what sort of object `gensim.downloader.api.load()` might deliver in this case, and I don't recommend that method's use due to the security considerations I've raised with the gensim project at issue https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/2283. (Instead, I recommend you download the `GoogleNews` vector file separately, explicitly, then load it into a specific model class object using a method like `.load_word2vec_format()`.

Comment: What you've reported as your `dictionary` hasn't printed like a Python dict object, so it's har to interpret. (Why are their ints both before and after each word, and a stray `4` at the top?) But more generally, if you just want the pairwise similarity between 2 words, the `.similiarity()` method on the `KeyedVectors` object is best. `.similarity_matrix()` is a special kind of truncated similarity, used for the "Soft Cosine" measure of set-of-words to set-of-words similarities.

Comment: @gojomo It delievers a Word2VecKeyedVectors model. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: The dictionary is not a python dict, is a [gensim dictionary](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/corpora/dictionary.html#gensim.corpora.dictionary.Dictionary). Every row, the first number is the following strings id, and the second number is how many times it appeared in documents I gave the dictionary.

Comment: Are you trying to prepare things for soft-cosine-similarity of sets-of-words, or do you just want word-to-word similarities?

Comment: @gojomo soft-cosine similarity of set-of-words.

Comment: Aha, OK. Well, when I look at the source code – https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/ec222e8e3e72608a59805040eadcf5c734a2b96c/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py#L624 – it appears that method is marked as `deprecated` (which should generate a warning when you run it). And, the demo notebook – https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/docs/notebooks/soft_cosine_tutorial.ipynb – shows a way of using `SoftCosineSimilarity` without specifically using that method. What happens if you follow that method, never using this method? Are there problems with those results/steps?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210687/discussion-between-eugene-asare-and-gojomo).

Comment: No chat. Chat seems to hide useful discussion/details/answers from future searchers, so I prefer working through things in discussion threads.

Comment: Sorry about that, I am new to contributing on the platform and it suggested that I'd do so. So I did try that method but the SparseTermSimilarityMatrix ends up being the exact same thing, as it is made the same way as it is in the depreciated method – https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py – the depreciated method makes the WordEmbeddingSimilarityIndex, then uses that to create a SparseTermSimilarityMatrix and returns the matrix in side it.

Comment: OK, that's useful - but how do the final results of the soft-cosine-similarity comparison look? Are they useful/sensible? (Maybe zeros in this interim, not-intended-for-external-consumption matrix are normal & don't hurt the final results.)

Comment: I think they are better for longer sentences or 'documents' but this method doesn't seem to work well for short descriptions and search queries, which is what I need it for. The comparison collapses to matching the words in the sentences I am testing on.

I have a new approach in mind, which is to create my own matrix, manually assigning the similarities in it.

Comment: OK, there may very well be a bug - as my understanding is soft-cosine *should* work well for short phrases/titles/etc. You may want to report the anomalies (both in the interim matrix, & the unsatisfactory results) as a bug report at the gensim project: <https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues> - & perhaps someone with more familiarity with how this should work can comment/investigate.

Comment: Depending on the volume of pairwise comparisons you need to make, you may also want to look at "Word Mover's Distance" (WMD) – available as a `.wmdistance()` method in `gensim` ``KeyedVectors`. It's expensive to calculate, but most likely to be practical on short texts. And, the 'soft cosine' measure has been touted as being "almost as good as WMD but cheaper to calculate".